# Overflow hidden hides complete picture in one direction, but not the other

Tags: html, css

This is my code (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bsjnq/)):

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.image-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have lots of images, all 200px squared, in an `image-container`. The overflowing images are hidden.

When I slide the images to the left, the left-most image disappears in a smooth fashion.

When I slide the images to the right, the right-most image *does not* disappear in a smooth fashion. Instead, it disappears in a flash.

Why is there a discrepancy between the left and right behaviour? How can I have a smooth animation on both sides?

Comment: When you turn off `overflow` you can see it visually.  After clicking the `right` button, the last element is pushed (wrapped) onto the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `white-space:nowrap`

```
     img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.image-container {
    white-space:nowrap;
    height: 200px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/bsjnq/3/

Answer (score 2):

What's because your image container isn't wide enough, and the images are dropping down to the next line but the overflow is hiding that.

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bsjnq/2/)**.

Wrap your image container in a wrapper with the CSS you currently have on your image container, and make your image container as wide as all your images combined (4000px for kicks in my example).

```
.image-container {
    width: 4000px;
    height: 200px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```